# How To Produce The Data Classes in .NET 2.0 platform using c# : A case study to get the answer

Tags: c#, .net, t4, auto-generate

I will show you my project to describe what I want to know about auto generation of code files:

Here the image about the project. You can see The Point A: A dataset which has three tables inside. Then focus on the Point B. *Please check the question below the image,*

[image: demonstrating the solution]

I would like to generate the DataObjects (in the Point B). Let me introduce the data objects codes what likely to be generated:

For instance:

```
   public class _BundleFlowData_SpColumns : SpColumns
    {
        public override IList<ColumnNames> Columns
        {
            get
            {
                return new CollectionOf<ColumnNames>()
                    .Add(ColumnNames.WFInstanceId)
                    .Add(ColumnNames.IsCustomer)
          ...
```

**Is it possible to create the data objects when I create the dataset or update the data set ?
I heard about T4, Is it possible to do it with T4 (or any other solution will be perfect)?
The data objects auto generation may be triggered by updating or creating the dataset in the main solution..**

Comment: Are you looking for pure .NET 2.0?   Are you able to use .NET 3.0/3.5 which is basically the same runtime as .NET 2.0?

Comment: @Naraen, for pure .NET 2.0 and it is VS 2005

Answer (score 1):

You can generate classes directly from the .xsd by using a tool such as [Xsd2Code](http://xsd2code.codeplex.com/), which can be integrated into your build process.

Comment: how can I give the design of class implementation, for instance _BundleFlowData_SpColumns class file in the question. It has static parts like public class.... and dynamic parts like the column names ( depends on the total number of the columns in the three table.) Could you please tell me more about how to use it?